# Какими библиотеками можно воспользоваться для рисования логических схем?

Tags: c#, nuget

Я хочу нарисовать логическую схему используя стороннюю библиотеку.

Например такую:

[image: Логическая схема]

Обычно я каждый раз сам реализовывал алгоритм рисования, но в этот раз хочу воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой.

Comment: не уверен, что понял вашу проблему. Вы пишете аналог Visio и ищите готовый пакет для этого?

Comment: Я ищу готовы пакет с помощью которого на C# можно было бы на рисовать схему. Пока что нашел yworks (https://www.yworks.com) и пытаюсь с помощью него решить данную проблему.